# Outlook VSTO Add-in selected text and context menu in Mail subject

Tags: c#, vsto, outlook-addin

I'm writing an Outlook 2016 VSTO Add-in in c# to add some lookup functionality. I already managed to create a context menu item when right clicking in an email body. The code in the handler accesses the current selection and executes my lookup functionality. So far so good.[Screenshot of working context menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OVFtj.png)

Now I also would like to add an item to the context menu when right clicking on the email subject (in the reading pane above the body). Although looking in "Office2016FluentUserInterfaceControlIdentifiers" I couldn't find the idMso.

Question 1: What is the idMso of this context menu?

Next problem is here that it also seems difficult to access the current selection - the way via `ActiveInspector.WordEditor.Application.Selection.Text` or `ActiveExplorer.Selection[1].GetInspector.WordEditor.Application.Selection.Text` did work for the Email body but not for the subject above.
[Screenshot of selected text in subject](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K3fxx.png)

Question 2:How to access the current selection in the email subject?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What about using Explorers object and get a Selection explorer as mentioned [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.explorer?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=outlook-pia)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Preview pane body - use `Explorer.ActiveInlineResponseWordEditor`.
Subject edit box - the best you can do is use Windows API to find the control's HWND and then retrieve the selection using [EM_GETSEL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/em-getsel) message.

Comment: Hi Dmitry, thanks for the answer - I was already afraid that WinAPI is the way to go here. Any idea on question1 - How can I find the control ID of the context menu?

Comment: I don't think that menu is exposed at all.