# how to add button in outlook mail body right Click context menu?

Tags: c#, vsto, outlook-addin, add-in

I want to add button in outlook mail body right lick context menu in vsto C# add-in how it possible.

this button get selected text from mail body in read mode.

like this screenshot [see screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZSLxh.png)

I find a question a person @Martin will do this but dose not provide any code example.
In this question [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58935503/22866607)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both the preview pane and Outlook inspectors use Word-light to display and edit messages. While full-blown Word lets you modify context menus from COM addins, you cannot do that when Word is used inside Outlook. That functionality is simply not exposed in the Outlook Object Model.

Comment: thanks @DmitryStreblechenko  it's mean that is not possible?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.